# Google Drive - service account storage limitation

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm planning to use [Google Drive *service* account](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts) because my application will be using it to store Realtime API documents. These will be [shortcut files](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/application#shortcut_files).  On [help page](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts) it says:

> Because it is not possible to access the Google Drive web user interface of a service account, it is not possible to purchase additional Google Drive storage for this type of accounts. For that reason you may prefer using a regular account instead of a service account.

I seen [5GB figure floating around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434186/google-drive-service-accounts-additional-storage). Should I be worried about it if I'm only creating shortcut files? Is this limitation imposed purposefully? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcut files take zero quota, so you should be fine.

Comment: Kind of what I figured. Still wondering why they impose this limitation of not allowing to increase quota for service account...

Comment: That is something that will be fixed.