# Space occupied by files uploaded using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a Google Service Account to upload and download files using Google Drive API.

I have a quota of 100 GB in my main Google Drive account.

The files that I upload using the Google Drive API counts to this 100 Gb?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based off previous information ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604248/google-drive-service-account-storage-limitation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434186/google-drive-service-accounts-additional-storage)) it seems the service account has its own storage that you may not  be able to increase. I'm not entirely sure if this still stands today, as I could not find any other information in the docs. If it *is* the case, you may want to use your actual account (which would share the storage), if you need more space. I believe for larger storage size, [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview) would be better than Drive.